# Better way to return conditional rxjs Observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

In the following code, are the functions `onReady1()` and `onReady2()` equivalent? What are the differences? Is there a better way to write this function?

The `onReadyx()` functions should return the user if it is available right away, or it would wait until its available. There will be multiple calls to this function at any given time.

```
export class UserService {
    private _user: IUser;

    private userObservable: Observable<IUser>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.userObservable = this.getCurrentUser();
    }

    public onReady1() {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<IUser>) => {
            if (this._user) {
                observer.next(this._user);
                observer.complete();
                return;
            }

            this.userObservable.subscribe(user => {
                this._user = user;
                observer.next(user);
                observer.complete();
            });
        });
    }

    public onReady2() {
        return Observable.defer(() => {
            if (this._user) {
                return Observable.of(this._user);
            }

            return this.userObservable.do(user => this._user = user);
        });
    }

    private getCurrentUser() {
        return this.http.get('/currentuser')
            .map(response => response.json() as IUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that ? are you trying to cache the user ?

Comment: @n00dl3 yes. I get a token in the `IUser` which I want to use for subsequent service calls.

Comment: then go for @JuliaPassynkova 's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use publishLast

```
export class Service {
  private sharedStream$: Observable< IUser>;

 constructor(public http: AuthHttp) {
   this.sharedStream$ = this. getCurrentUser()
    .publishLast()
    .refCount();
 }

 getUserObservable(): Observable< IUser> {
  return this.sharedStream$;
 }
}
```